# How can I run Python CGI scripts on my web server?

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I want to run a Python CGI script on my web server (Apache 2.2). When I try to run the `test.py` file I get the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /test.py
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

In the error log:

```
[client 127.0.0.1] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/test.py
```

So what could be the problem?

Comment: You can't run Python scripts in the browser. Did you mean you want to run them on the server when the browser makes a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error log is telling you that your Web server isn't configured to allow running CGI scripts from that directory.

See [How do I enable CGI execution in directories other than the ScriptAlias?](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#CGIoutsideScriptAlias) in the Apache FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Options ExecCGI` to a `.htaccess` file in the folder where the python file is located.

Besides that, don't use CGI but WSGI to execute python apps...

Answer (score 0):

Try mod_python.it's an apache module which gets embedded in apache itself and allow users to run python scripts on