# Run python cgi script in browser w/o errors

Tags: python, browser, cgi, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to run it on **localhost**.
A short introduction. Some links I've read before post:
[How to run Python CGI script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929848/how-to-run-python-cgi-script)
[How can I run Python CGI scripts on my web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611608/how-can-i-run-python-cgi-scripts-on-my-web-server)
most precise: [Need Help to Configure apache Server to run CGI Script written in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044232/need-help-to-configure-apache-server-to-run-cgi-script-written-in-python)
And also official http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#CGIoutsideScriptAlias
http://www.editrocket.com/articles/python_apache_windows.html
and other...

---

All steps they suggest to configure Apache for .cgi and .py scripts:
1)

> install libapache2-mod-wsgi

[done]
2) check the script is executable and available for apache
~$ ls -lah /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi101.py

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 318 2012-11-27 03:03 /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi101.py
```

3) edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default[**updated to actual**]:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
#   <Directory /var/www>
    <Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
#       AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

or with

```
<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>
```

then restart Apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and finally, try the script. Something like[**updated to actual**]:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# parse form data
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
# hdr plus blank line
print('<title>Reply Page</title>')
# html reply page
if not 'user' in form:
  print('<h1>Who are you?</h1>')
else:
  print('<h1>Hello <i>%s</i>!</h1>' % cgi.escape(form['user'].value))
```

On the output i get

> **404 Not found**

error. WTH? I've tried both  and /var/www. And my python path to python3:

```
~$ ls -lah /usr/bin/python*
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 2011-10-05 23:53 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 2012-10-20 06:17 /usr/bin/python3.2 -> python3.2mu
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.8M 2012-10-20 06:17 /usr/bin/python3.2mu
...
```

that's why i use

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Thanks in advance!

---

[**updated**]
/var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Tue Nov 27 13:47:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.py, referer: http://localhost/cgi1$
```

Why it looks for script.py in /usr/lib/ ??

---

[**updated**]
I closed my eyes while reading the lines

```
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
```

It must be path to executable .cgi or .py in /var/www/cgi-bin. Thanks Evert and everyone!

Comment: 404: what URL are you accessing? And perhaps other parts of your config are incomplete? Assuming there's a default `index.html` , do you get to see that one at least when visiting http://127.0.0.1/ ?

Comment: i open /localhost/cgi-bin/script.py - the actual path where the script is and where apache has access. There is no index.html/index.php/index.else

Comment: Surely you mean `http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.py`? My apache configuration is a bit rusty, but possibly, you can leave off the .py extension there as well. But for your (and our) sanity, it'd be good to put an (empty) index.html file in `/var/www/` and see if you can at least find that.

Comment: Yes! localhost/index.html and localhost/index.php can be found! Even <?php phpinfo() ?> testpage works fine. But it is about php, not python...

Comment: No, it's about an executable, whether that be shell, python, perl or php (the php you're seeing goes through modphp, not modcgi). You could try a perl script instead, but that will probably also fail. But that's beside the point.

Comment: `script.py` or `cgi101.py`? Just be careful with renaming things, that gets confusing.

Comment: You don't need to be installing 'install libapache2-mod-wsgi'. Has got nothing to do with CGI scripts. The mod_wsgi package would only have come up in as much as people would have been suggesting you not use CGI scripts, but instead use a WSGI server/adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you have your script in `/var/www/cgi-bin/cgi101.py`.

But your Apache configuration has this:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

and add the `AddHandler` directive in there as well:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
    </Directory>
```

(and perhaps remove the section above this one, for the `/var/www` directory.)

I would then put your script at `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/cgi101.py`, and try again.

The [Apache tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) seems actually pretty clear on this.

Comment: Just noticed the update, which tells *exactly* what I say above ;-).

Comment: Thank you !!! Works perfectly. Probably I have eyes in ... somewhere else than where they should be.

Answer (score 0):

At first you must be sure that your script can be run by Python/OS. In your case you try to use Python3 and I see that you use old form of `print`. For Python3 you must use `print()` as function. Your script must run when you try to execute it from command line. Make sure it has `execute` attribute.

When you script will run from command line then you can try to run it via CGI. When in trouble check `http` server logs. They will probably be in `/var/log/http` and there should be `error.log`. Check it.

Also make sure that your file use unix type EndOfLine, i.e. LF only, not CRLF from DOS/Windows. If you use CRLF then first line (shebang) is corrupted.

Also you must separate HTTP headers from content using empty line. So instead of

```
print("Content-Type: text/html")
```

use:

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
```

Comment: If the script won't run, the status returned to the browser will be 500, not 404.

Comment: You are right. Then maybe it is incorrect URL. But at first I would make it runnable from command line, then I would check http server logs.

Comment: I've done this before posting, the script runs successfully in shell (~$ python3 /var/www/cgi-bin/script.py). And the problem is really in apache configuration. i'm sure.

Comment: And sorry for misunderstanding, all above was correct, i actually use print() for py3.

Comment: Also try to execute your script from shell as: `~$ /var/www/cgi-bin/script.py` i.e. not by python3, but via shebang (first line in your script).

Comment: $ /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi101.py 
'Content-type: text/html

<title>Reply Page</title>
<h1>Who are you?</h1>' -- runs exactly how it should

Comment: I've tried with **#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'** but it gives the same 404. Running in terminal gives the same good result.

Comment: So you must look at Apache logs. Especially `access.log` and `error.log`